# SQL query to fetch rows based on a column

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table Employee as below. The Change column contains names of columns whose values are modified through my application. Data in this column is separated by comma. I need to query this table in such a way that the result will have one change per row. ie split the data in the Change column by comma and fetch the corresponding row. I don't have an idea where to start ! Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see, you could use Oracle's `regexp_substr` function:

```
select distinct Id, Name, Address, trim(regexp_substr(Change,'[^,]+', 1, level)) 
from Employee
connect by regexp_substr(Change, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

This should work for any number of comma-separated values in your `Change` column.

See doc on the rexexp_substr function here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm

Answer (score 1):

here i have tried with the use of regexp_substr included multiset level

```
    with temp as
    (
       select id, name, address, change from testemp
    )
    select id,name,address,trim(regexp_substr(change, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value)) change
    from temp t,
    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual 
    connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(change, '[^,]+'))  + 1)
    as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels;
```